# open firefox about pages without the address bar

Tags: linux, firefox, javascript, about-config

I can't seem to open the firefox about pages without using the address bar.
I've tried this in javascript with no success :

```js
window.open('about:profiles')
```

Does anyone knows how can I do that ?
It seems that the about pages are just some "commands" to open a json file that is stored locally on my machine (but where ?), but I am not sure.

Comment: You didn't provide an operating system so I am forced to guess.  I don't get the point but poke around `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles` , you will find one folder that ends with `.default-release`.  Look in there.  All should become clear.  No, it isn't "a json file" but close.. it's a bunch of 'em and other stuff too.

Comment: thx, I found them (i'm on linux, so it's in `~/.mozilla/firefox`).

Comment: I updated your tags.  Thanks for clarifying.  I would have given you the Linux answer but didn't know what OS.  I am glad you have it now.  Enjoy the party of playing in that directory.

Comment: It seems like there is some restriction on about pages. I was able to run `window.open('about:blank')` with no issue but pages like `about:profiles` or `about:config` give the error `Uncaught Error: Access to 'about:profiles' from script denied`

Comment: BTW: a shortcut to an About: page, e.g., *about:config*, can be added as a bookmark *within* Firefox, but cannot be opened if dropped on the (Windows) desktop. Just tested out of curiosity.